# What does "I'm a loser, baby, so why don't you kill me?" mean?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

> Soy un perdedor
>
> I'm a loser, baby, so why don't you kill me?
>
> (Double barrel buckshot)
>
> Soy un perdedor
>
> I'm a loser, baby, so why don't you kill me?

https://genius.com/Beck-loser-lyrics
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loser_(Beck_song)

This is a very strange song in many ways, but the chorus/refrain in particular has always puzzled me. I've heard it (not the rest of the song) repeated many times in other contexts.

Why exactly would somebody kill somebody else because they are a loser? For some reason, I always assumed that the singer was singing about a popular/beautiful girl in school or something, and that she would "kill" him figuratively rather than literally.

"Soy un perdedor" just seems to mean "I'm a loser" in Spanish.

Answer (score 8):

**It's a hard song to understand unless you remember the ironic-nihilist, slacker culture of the times.** At the time, Gen-X teenagers and young adults were dismissed by their elders as aimless, apathetic, self-destructive "losers." Rather than fight this labeling, artists like Beck chose to wear it proudly, as a badge of honor. Like much youth music, this song is calculated to offend the sensibilities of the older generation --those being the earnestly unselfconscious Baby Boomers.

In that context, the line "I'm a loser, baby, so why don't you kill me?" means "If I'm such a waste of life, such a person with no redeeming qualities as you think I am, then why don't you quit complaining about me, and just go ahead and end my pathetic life?" **Picture it being sneered by a goth teenager** to a well-meaning but overbearing parent, teacher or coach.

Answer (score 0):

It's inspiration was thought from grunge music. To make a Mick from those calling certain people losers. Then it was even funnier when they were looking for some meaning. It is exactly what it is.
Be who you wanna be, say what you want. If someone is offended then that is on them.

Answer (score -3):

Loser is exactly like Nirvana's "In Bloom". It means nothing. It was intentional nonsense made to laugh at the people who claim to find meaning in it.

Comment: Although this isn't a great answer, I'm inclined to agree. The lyrics of this song are just random babbling and anyone trying to find some deeper meaning to them are likely the same kind who listen to "Stairway to Heaven" backwards.